# DotNetRDF & AllegroGraph

Tags: c#, allegrograph, dotnetrdf

I'm working on an application for bulk parsing and uploading to an AllegroGraph triplestore, but have run into a snag. I am able to open and read the graph in question using the below code:

```
        AllegroGraphConnector conn = new AllegroGraphConnector(myHost, myGraph, myUsername, myPassword);

        Graph g = new Graph();
        conn.LoadGraph(g, "");

        g.BaseUri = new Uri(MOG);
        foreach (RTSNode r in _nodes)
        {
            IUriNode sbj = g.CreateUriNode(new Uri(RTSuri + r.myName));
            IUriNode pred = g.CreateUriNode(new Uri(MOG));
            ILiteralNode obj = g.CreateLiteralNode(r.myName, "en");

            g.Assert(new Triple(sbj, pred, obj));
        }

        conn.SaveGraph(g);
```

As mentioned the graph loads fine and triples are being added to the local version. But when I attempt to save it, I get an 400- Bad request error. Turning on full debugging shows the error to be due to:

> UNSUPPORTED FILE FORMAT: 'application/n-triples' is not a supported content-type

Is there an option for changing the default format with which AllegroGraphConnector communicates?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What version of dotNetRDF are you using?

This sounds like a bug which was fixed in our recent 1.0.8 release so I would first try upgrading to the latest version which should resolve the issue

#### Update

So it looks like this is a bug in AllegroGraph, according to their [documentation](http://franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/current/http-protocol.html) they are expecting the MIME type for NTriples to be `text/plain` whereas most current systems (including dotNetRDF) use the now standard `application/n-triples` as the MIME type for NTriples.

Currently there is no workaround for this, filed as [CORE-447](http://dotnetrdf.org/tracker/Issues/IssueDetail.aspx?id=447) to be fixed for the next release

Comment: I grabbed the version off of NuGet: dotNetRDF - 1.0.8.3533